# I need to reference a cell that has a date on the sql code using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I have an Excel sheet that has a start date and end date that can be changed by the user. I have a second sheet that has a cell in which the user can input his query in order to get that information. I have assigned startDate and enDate to the query so it can reference those cells. The problem I am having is that because I am extracting the query from excel it does not reference the startdate and endate. Is there something I can do to fix this? Here is the query:

```
select system_date where system_date >= ' " & startDate & "" and
system_date <= "" & endDate & "# and action_id = 15 and log_desc not
like '%svc_openlink_p%' order by system_date
```

Here is the code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim dbConnectStr As String
Dim dbConnectStr1 As String
Dim objmyconn As ADODB.Connection
Set objmyconn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim recordCount As Long
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim j As Long, N As Long, r1 As Range
Dim dat As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim startDate   As String
Dim endDate As String
Dim dataName As String
Dim passWord As String
Dim serverName As String
Dim qryN As String




'code for the dates
startDate = Format(Worksheets("TotalExtraction").Range("C6").Value2, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
endDate = Format(Worksheets("TotalExtraction").Range("C8").Value2, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

'code for assigment

dataName = (Range("dataName").Value)
passWord = (Range("password").Value)
serverName = (Range("server").Value)
qryN = (Range("Query").Text)

dbConnectStr = "Provider=msdaora;User Id=" & Uname
dbConnectStr1 = "Provider=msdaora;User Id='" & dataName & "';Data Source='" & serverName & "';Pwd='" & passWord & "'"

    objmyconn.ConnectionString = dbConnectStr & dbConnectStr1
    objmyconn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
    objmyconn.Open dbConnectStr 'ConnectionString'
    'Declare variables'

'Set objmyconn = New ADODB.Connection
Set Sql = New ADODB.Command
Set ds = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strsql As String
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim i As Long
i = 2

Worksheets("IndividualUsers").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B4:M30000").Clear

        'Set and Execture SQL Command
Set Sql.ActiveConnection = objmyconn
Sql.CommandText = qryN
MsgBox qryN
Sql.CommandType = adCmdText
Sql.Execute
```

Comment: You could have the start and end dates as named ranges in the workbook so the user can simply reference them in the query string?

Comment: What do you mean "it does not reference the startdate and endate"?

Comment: Actually, that might cause some issues with the format of the dates. Could you not just use `Replace`? e.g. `qryN=Replace(Replace(qryN,"startDate",startDate),"endDate",endDate)`

Comment: Debug.Print the final SQL and update your question with it: without knowing exactly what the SQL is it's impossible to make good suggestions here.

Comment: @Jordan you code worked!!! The only thing is that its giving me an error saying " ora-00904: "Apr": Invalid identifier. Do you think its because its reading it as a text and not a date?

Comment: The format of 'startDate' and 'endDate' need to match how they are stored in your database. You're currently formatting them as `dd-mmm-yyyy` so you may need to change this format.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a parameterized query where you bind parameter date values in VBA prior to executing. This avoids passing values into select statement which is not recommended practice. Also, in doing so, you do not need to concatenate quotes around parameters.

Save the following in the *Query* Range *(do include question marks)*

```
="SELECT system_date 
  FROM TableName
  WHERE system_date BETWEEN ? AND ? 
  AND action_id = 15 
  AND log_desc NOT LIKE '%svc_openlink_p%' 
  ORDER BY system_date"
```

VBA script *(end portion)*

```
...

'Set and Execture SQL Command
With Sql
    .ActiveConnection = objmyconn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = qryN

    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("startDateParam", adDate, adParamInput)
    .Parameters(0).Value = startDate
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("endDateParam", adDate, adParamInput)
    .Parameters(1).Value = endDate

    .Execute
End With
```

By the way, be sure to specify a *TableName* in query and check connection strings. Finally, be sure date formats properly align to your database. Usually in RDMS, the format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.